# Statistics: Rao-Cramer Lower Bound

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, variance

I was reviewing Rao-Cramer Lower Bound and noticed that in some scenarios, the formula indicates $$var(y) \geq  \frac{k'(\theta)^2}{nI(\theta)},$$ and other times we do not include the numerator.

$k$ is the expectation of $y$. If possible can someone explain when do I include it and when do I not?

Comment: The expression in your post gives the CR lower bound for any function $k(\cdot)$ of the parameter $\theta$. When $k(\theta)=\theta$, the numerator is $1$.

Comment: Thank you. I will be sure to keep that in mind :D